# How to create submenu inside submenu in magento 2 admin?

Tags: magento2

How to create submenu inside submenu in magento 2 admin?
3 level child menu in admin
[image]

Comment: Hi Junaid, Can you elaborate more? Any screenshot or structure that you want?

Comment: i have mentioned picture

Comment: i want when i click on unit 3 under extension then 2nd column will show

Answer (score 1):

You need to do custom work for adding submenu child because in Magento's core menu xsd it is not defined:

```
vendor\magento\module-backend\etc\menu.xsd
```

Here you can see below schema that is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="config">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="menu">
                     <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:element name="add">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:documentation>
                                            Action designed for adding new item to existing items as a child
                                        </xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="typeId" use="required" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="required" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="module" type="typeModule" use="required" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="sortOrder" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="action" type="typeAction" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="parent" type="typeId" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="toolTip" type="typeTitle" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="resource" type="typeResource" use="required" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="dependsOnModule" type="typeModule" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="dependsOnConfig" type="typeDependsConfig" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="translate" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="update">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:documentation>
                                            Action designed for updating existing menu items attributes
                                        </xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="typeId" use="required" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="module" type="typeModule" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="sortOrder" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="action" type="typeAction" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="parent" type="typeId" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="toolTip" type="typeTitle" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="resource" type="typeResource" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="dependsOnModule" type="typeModule" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="dependsOnConfig" type="typeDependsConfig" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="translate" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="remove">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:documentation>
                                            Action designed for removing existing menu item with its children
                                        </xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="typeId" use="required" />
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="uniqueAddItemId">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation>
                                Attribute id is unique under add actions
                            </xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:selector xpath="add"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeId">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Item id attribute can has only [a-z0-9/_]. Minimal length 3 symbol. Case insensitive.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9/_:]{3,}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeAction">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Item action attribute can has only [a-zA-Z0-9/_]. Minimal length 3 symbol
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9/_\-]{3,}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeTitle">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Item title attribute minimal length 3 symbol
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="3" />
            <xs:maxLength value="50" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeModule">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Item module attribute can has only [a-z0-9_]. Minimal length 3 symbol. Case insensitive.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeResource">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Item resource attribute can has only [a-z0-9_]. Minimal length 3 symbol. Case insensitive.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeDependsConfig">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Item resource attribute can has only [a-z0-9_]. Minimal length 3 symbol. Case insensitive.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9_/]{3,}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

So you can add only one submenu.

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/source/_module.less

```
.admin__menu ._show .submenu .parent {
    display: table-cell;
}
.admin__menu ._show .submenu .item-menu2{
    display: none;
}
.admin__menu ._show .submenu .item-menu2.active{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        "Vendor_Module/js/main"
    ]
};
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/main.js

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

                $(".level-2").click(function() {
                    $(".item-menu2.parent.level-1").addClass("active");
                });
                $(".admin__menu .action-close").click(function() {
                    $(".item-menu2.parent.level-1").removeClass("active");
                });
    });
```